# Android - Screen not updating when removing view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

This is my first Android app to get my hands wet. The app's sole purpose is to make and store lists. I'm having an issue with the screen not correctly updating itself when I create a new list and add it to the screen. For the sake of learning as much as possible about how the views and layouts I've ignored all the themes. Any way I have a linear layout with a custom button that is essentially another linear layout. The app looks like this when you first start it! (I need 10 rep to post images so for now you get this)

```
***********************************************
* List Of Lists                  |  +  | | * |*
*---------------------------------------------*
*                                             *
*         Start Making Lists                  *
*                 +                           *
*---------------------------------------------*
*                                             *
*                                             *
```

After you click Start Making Lists and enter a string into the popup that appears I get this issue where the 1st button gets removed but the screen is redrawn improperly.

```
***********************************************
* List Of Lists                  |  +  | | * |*
*---------------------------------------------*
*                 Test Label                  *
*---------------------------------------------*
*                 +                           *
*---------------------------------------------*
```

In case you can't tell from my ascii art there is a leftove portion from the original button that was there. You can't click it so it behaves like it is gone but my plus image and the shaded background still show.

The Code, or at least what I think you need to see

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        init();

        /* Start DB Gather data */
        listData = new ListDB(this); //extends SQLiteOpenHelper
        Cursor listNames = listData.getListNames(0);

        if (listNames.getCount() > 0)
        {
            /* Regular processing */
            createStandardView(listNames);
        }
        else
        {
            /* No lists yet, special view for new users */
            createNoListView();
        }

        /* Draw the view to the screen */
        setContentView(screen);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        TextView errMsg = new TextView(this);
        String err = e.toString() + "\n";
        StackTraceElement[] stack = e.getStackTrace();

        for(int i = 0; i < stack.length; ++i)
        {
            err += stack[i].toString() + "\n";
        }
        errMsg.setText(err.subSequence(0, err.length()));
        setContentView(errMsg);
    }
}
```

The issue Kind of comes in in the call to createNoListView() so here is that code

```
/**
* Creates the initial view the user will see when they first install the app / have no lists yet. This layout could
* have been and should be in a seperate xml file like any other static android layout
*/
public void createNoListView()
{
    /* Default Fresh Install add new list button view */
    final WideButton btnAddNew = new WideButton(this, R.string.btnAddText, R.drawable.add_new);
    btnAddNew.setId(1);
    btnAddNew.setImageDimensions(35,35);
    btnAddNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            actionBar.addNewList();
        }
    });

    llMain.addView(btnAddNew);
}
```

The WideButton class is a udf class I made. It extends LinearLayout and contains a textview and imageview. I'll be more than happy to post that class if anyone thinks it would help.

So here is where the trouble actually happens. When the user clicks and we get into actionBar.addNewList(). FYI ActionBar is a custom class I made in spite of the API providing a similiar feature. ActionBar is a private class to the class that is currently being executed. Action bar implements View.onCLickListener. Here is the addNewList() function. Also llMain is a linearLayout

```
/**
    * Starts the process of creating a new list.
    * */
    public void addNewList()
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)action_bar.getContext()).getLayoutInflater();

        final View vwDiag = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_list_diag, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListOfLists.this);

        alert.setView(vwDiag).setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id)
            {
                /* Add the list to the DB*/
                EditText txtNameVal = (EditText) vwDiag.findViewById(R.id.txtNameVal);
                String listName = txtNameVal.getText().toString();

                //Display new item
                if(listData.getListCount() == 0)
                {
                    ((LinearLayout)ListOfLists.this.llMain.findViewById(1)).removeAllViews();
                    //ListOfLists.this.llMain.removeViewAt(0);
                    //ListOfLists.this.llMain.refreshDrawableState();
                    ListOfLists.this.llMain.removeAllViews();
                }

                listData.createList(listName);
                addListToView(listName, null, null);
            }
        }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id){
        }}).create().show();
    }
}
```

As you can see I've tried a number of different things. Other things I have tried were.

```
//first attempt if I remember correctly
View btnAddNew = ListOfLists.this.llMain.findViewById(1);
ListOfLists.this.llMain.removeView(btnAddNew);

//Another one I'm sure I've done
View btnAddNew = ListOfLists.this.llMain.findViewById(1);
ListOfLists.this.llMain.removeView(btnAddNew);
ListOfLists.this.llMain.invalidate();
```

I've also done every combination of these commands I could think of that seemed at least somewhat logical. If you need to see more code just ask. I just thought it might be innapropriate to post my entire app so far on here.

Comment: In createNoListView I set the id to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so not the way to populate a data screen. I don't mean to sound impolite but your fundamental approach is wrong here. You're basically doing everything -- from interacting with your data model to manipulating the view hierarchy directly -- from within your `Activity` itself.

That's not the Android way of doing things. What you need is an `Adapter` -- the go-between component between your data and the views that make use of it.

You need to (optionally) extend from a `ListActivity` (which would come with its own `ListView`) but bind a `ListAdapter` (most likely a `SimpleCursorAdapter` since you're fetching data from a database)  to your `ListView` that's either supplied explicitly by you through a *layout* file, or using the default one supplied by the `ListActivity` when you *extend* from it.

Only the `Adapter` would interact with your data model classes. When the underlying data `List` changes, a call to `Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()` would refresh the `ListView` for you automatically.

Take a look at the [Android Developers' List View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) tutorial to get the hang of the basics. If you feel that the `CursorAdapter` is a wee bit more complex for you right now, start with using an `ArrayAdapter` first. Here's a good [ListView example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) on that.

Don't get scared on seeing so many different classes floating around. It gets easier later on.

Comment: How would I go about creating a view when there is nothing in the database? I discovered this option while doing research for this app but didn't implement it for this reason. An immediate answer I would assume to be to use a frame view but maybe you have a better suggestion.

Comment: That's quite simple actually. Just call `ListView#setEmptyView()` and pass in a `TextView` initialised with an appropriate message. If the data `List` backing your `ListAdapter` is empty, then on the first layout pass (if the `List` starts out as empty) or once you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter (after clearing the list), your `TextView` would automatically be shown to the user.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance of this answer. I haven't been able to work on this in a little bit. thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, no problem there. Glad my answer helped.